# Google thinks my domain doesn't exist or is misspelled when users search for it

Tags: google, url, search

I created a website for ecommerce, but am having problems with the Google search. My site link is "banilla.com.br" or "www.banilla.com.br", but Google thinks they are both misspellings (on either google.com and google.com.br since I'm from Brazil).

The worst is that when I type "www.banilla.com.br" (with www) it shows only "Showing results for balilla.com.br", it doesn't even show the "Search instead for banilla.com.br", so there is no way it would go to the correct link! =(

Comment: Although you are typing your domain in the _search box_, rather than the _address bar_. Unfortunately many end users do this, so you have my sympathy! But I don't think there's much you can do about this unfortunately, other than educate your users(!).

Comment: Does a search for *site:banilla.com.br* or *site:www.banilla.com.br* return any results??

Answer (score 4):

A site needs to exist for a while and get popular before Google will recommend it for its brand name and URL.

The good news is that Google *is* indexing your site and will show it in search results in "verbatim" mode:

[image: banilla search results]

This indicates that Google knows about the website and will show it if you say "I really mean what I'm searching for, don't show me synonyms or misspellings."

I had a site that had a similar issue.   When I first launched my site for my software named "Attesoro", Google thought that it was a misspelling of something else.   The site has been up for several years now, and today if you search for it you get "SiteLinks" which is an indication that Google thinks the site is the most relevant thing for that search:

[image]

The solution was simply to wait.   Google will correct itself as your site gets popular.   It may take a year for your site to be recognized as not a misspelling.   It may take another year to get site links.

Comment: Do you have an idea if providing quality content that Google appreciates speeds up the process? Thanks.

Comment: Quality content will help only indirectly: it will help your website get popular faster.

Answer (score 0):

The misspelling issue in Google search especially for new websites is a common one. And yes, many webmasters will face it. But you don't have to worry, with time, this goes automatically.

On your site showing the naked version (non-www) in search results, this is what you can fix yourself through Google search console. You only need to log in, access the site you want to show its www version, hit the gear icon, select site settings and make your preference. Its all simple and easy to do. After, wait for Google to make changes.

Comment: As the non-www version is already better indexed, it may make sense to make that the preferred version.