# How can Google find my company if my company name intentionally has a typo in it

Tags: seo, google, search

I have a company which has an intentional spelling error in its name, the problem is that, understandably so, people who might be searching for it in google will likely search it with the proper dictionary spelling, and beyond that even if they spell the way the company spells it google thinks its a typo and automatically adjusts its results to the proper spelling.

So I understand that it isn't good practice to hide keywords on the site, so what would be the best way for Google to find the site even if the search is spelt in the grammatically correct manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it may be seen as a different question the answer has largely been dealbt with here [Google thinks my domain doesn't exist or is misspelled when users search for it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79497/google-thinks-my-domain-doesnt-exist-or-is-misspelled-when-users-search-for-it?rq=1)

The fastest way to correct this is to make your site the authoritative for your company name. The sooner your site is seen by Google to be **the** destination for your (misspelled word) company name the sooner Google will be direct people to your site for that keyword search instead of offering them alternatives.

You may be tempted to include the non-misspelled version of the company name in your pages as a keyword, but there's two problems with that:

1. if it is a very popular word then you enter into a highly competitive market for that keyword, one which you may not be able to win and so consign your website to relative obscurity. I am assuming that was possibly your reason for choosing a misspelling in the first place - to stand out from the crowd.
2. you set back your attempts to gain Google's favour for your misspelled keyword by diluting focus and either make it a slower process to achieve notoriety for your misspelled name or potentially even negate it.

In the meantime, you can search Google for site:yourdomainname.com to see what links are already in Google's index for your site, or click the "Search Results" button and the All Results dropdown and select "Verbatim" to get specific results related to your misspelling.

[image: Selecting 'verbatim' results]

So again it comes back to making your site the best it can be for your keywords - quality unique content, good titles and semantics etc.

The good news is, since your company name is probably quite rare or even unique, you will have very little competition, and once Google as realised that the misspelling is a real 'thing' you are likely to receive Sitelinks fairly early on even without much traffic.

Comment: Nice answer!! ;-) I am just going to add this link: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87089/branding-in-terms-of-seo/87092#87092 It is not perfect, but the linked answers in this answer do give a few steps to take for branding. In order to make your misspelled word appear in the auto-suggest and not corrected, it would be an up-hill climb that requires a heavy win in the site branding category. It can be done!! Keep in mind that a site with a very active audience is the strongest tool in the box.

Comment: There is one thing that I'm still unsure of, and I think that is where my question slightly differs from the question you linked in your answer. The company is called Captve (captive without the i) and it produces high end jewellery. My worry (other than the google autocorrect) is that the people who haven't seen how its spelled will look for Captive Jewellery rather than Captve Jewellery. Since the name doesn't relate to the product in the first place I'm thinking maybe its not so bad if the keyword Captive is in there somewhere. Maybe your second point still trumps that though...

Comment: @fred I don't know what your logo looks like, but surely isn't it highly likely that people will simply miss seeing the lack of an "i" ? And it is proven that people will unconsciously add expected vowels where needed - so yes, it is highly likely people are going to search for Captive Jewelry. In your case maybe add both, but I'm not sure this changes things. You own both the domains - redirect one to the other. Once the primary domain has some history, my guess is that Google will display your site for either search anyway.

Comment: yeah I got both, I guess the answer is patience